# Is It mandatory to migrate from GCM to FCM for chrome/browser notification

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have an App created via GCM. I use its API Key and Project number for my chrome notification.

My Question is should I migrate to FCM(As GCM is not no longer going to support).As I explored  I found that it is required for Android Only.

Also will I be able to use this API Key and Project number after May 29, 2019 for sending chrome notifications

Comment: If you read further, there is also a [guide for iOS migration](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm). So I think this is applicable to all. And there is an [inquiry](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) for the web API's (Webpush protocol and chrome.gcm API). Also, you can check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#next_steps) for further details. As for the API key, if it is a very old server key, I suggest to proceed on using a new one.

Comment: Thanks MαπμQμαπkγVπ, So what I understood is that I Can use My existing GCM Server Key, Only need to change the API End point  to fcm for sendning notifications